# Why does buildroot reject my custom device tree directory?

Tags: embedded-linux, buildroot, device-tree

In order to use a custom device tree I made the below arrangements:

1. To eliminate possible device tree syntax errors I just downloaded original dts file and changed it's name as custom-bananapro.dts . (If this comes nonsense to you I just wanted to be sure that I know all steps of the -howtocustomdevicetree- process)
2. I saved custom-bananapro.dts into the /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg directory.
3. And made following changes at buildroot's menuconfig
4. In-tree Device Tree Source file names = custom-bananapro
5. Out-of-tree Device Tree Source file path = /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg
   .

But buildroot build process resulted in the below error message :

> cp -f /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/output/build/linux-5.4.7/arch/arm/boot/dts/
> cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg
> make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:283: /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/output/build/linux-5.4.7/.stamp_built] Error 1
> make: *** [Makefile:82: _all] Error 2

Then at my subsequent try in addition to above I also changed u-boot device tree configuration as:

> BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH=/home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg

Again buildroot build process resulted in a similar error message :

> cp -f /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/output/build/uboot-2022.04/arch/arm/dts/
> cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg'
> make[1]: *** [package/pkg-generic.mk:283: /home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/output/build/uboot-2022.04/.stamp_built] Error 1
> make: *** [Makefile:82: _all] Error 2

Comment: I kept the above changes and made some more from uboot-menuconfig. At uboot from Device Tree Control menu I erased Default Device Tree for DT control and from Boot Options menu I set Default fdt file as custom-bananapro. Then I rebuild linux with make linux-rebuild. The same result :

Comment: Is it a whole error message? If so, then it complains that it want to treat your *my_oleg* forlder as file and of course fail. You need to read more documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`BR2_TARGET_UBOOT_CUSTOM_DTS_PATH` takes a list of filenames to copy, E.G. you should set it to `/home/oleg/Documents/buildroot/my_oleg/custom-bananapro.dts`.

The help text tries to explain that:

```
Space-separated list of paths to device tree source files                                                              that will be copied to arch/ARCH/dts/ before starting the                                                                build.                                                                                                                 

To use this device tree source file, the U-Boot configuration                                                          file must refer to it.
```

But maybe that isn't clear? Can you suggest another wording?

Comment: Yes, it's not clear. Apparently POSIX terminology is to blame. A pathname can specify just a file rather than a subdirectory.  Ref: [filename and pathname of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146895/filename-and-pathname-of-a-file)

Comment: Apparently adding the file name at the end of path solved that particular problem. Of course now I have new different errors to fight. If I fail I will come again :)